# QGIS dynamic calculations in a label

Tags: qgis, labeling, dynamic

In order to show a label with different values, I use "concat". Now, I want to show a label with the numbers from that field, multiplied by a number (or the value from another field).

I want that calculation inside the label, live.

The other way is to create a new field with the calculation, and concatenate it in my label.
But, that means, any change in the source field needs also to be updated in the calculated field.

That's why I would like a dynamic calculation within the label.

Here's an example, where I want to multiply a value with a number and show the result in the concat label:

`Concatenate("[Field 1, a number]",'legend','\n','which represents:','"[Field 1, a number]"/[a number or a field with a number]', 'legend')`.

With this, the formula does not make the calculation, and only writes my formula as a caracter chain in the label.

Comment: It's not clear what does this concatenate do? Can't you just multiply two fields? "field1" * "field2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your String quote of `'"[Field 1, a number]"/[a number or a field with a number]'`. It should be written without the single quotes. Using `'` here will indicate this as string and no calculation will be done.

Try:

```
Concatenate("Field 1",'legend','\n','which represents:',"Field 1"/[a number or a field with a number], 'legend')
```

Comment: Thank you to MrWsquared, indeed the formula works now with live calculations. Now I would like to generalise to any calculations inside the "concat" formula. For instance, the result of my calculation is a decimal number with many digits. I want to only keep the two first decimal digits. But the "left" command inside the "concat" does not seem to work. I'm interessted in the right procedure to include any formula inside the concat formula.

Comment: You can use `round()` as usual, should be `Concatenate("Field 1",'legend','\n','which represents:',round("Field 1"/[a number or a field with a number],2), 'legend')`

Comment: I assume it's the same for any formula. Also, I rediscovered the "round" formula by the way. Thanks a lot.